# Convert some columns into row and one column's rows into columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, backend

I have one table in which I want to convert all the years column into row and one column's row should be converted into columns. Following is the sample table

| City | Sales | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 100 | 120 | 160 |
| A | Y | 90 | 120 | 130 |
| A | Z | 130 | 160 | 190 |
| B | X | 200 | 220 | 260 |
| B | Y | 290 | 220 | 230 |
| B | Z | 230 | 260 | 290 |
| C | X | 300 | 320 | 360 |
| C | Y | 390 | 320 | 330 |
| C | Z | 330 | 360 | 390 |

Final table looks like:

| City | Year | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2016 | 100 | 90 | 130 |
| A | 2017 | 120 | 120 | 160 |
| A | 2018 | 160 | 130 | 190 |
| B | 2016 | 200 | 290 | 230 |
| B | 2017 | 220 | 220 | 260 |
| B | 2018 | 260 | 230 | 290 |
| C | 2016 | 300 | 390 | 330 |
| C | 2017 | 320 | 320 | 360 |
| C | 2018 | 360 | 330 | 390 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `melt`:

```
>>> df.melt(['City', 'Sales'], var_name='Year', value_name=None) \ 
      .set_index(['City', 'Year', 'Sales']) \
      .squeeze().unstack().rename_axis(columns=None)

             X    Y    Z
City Year
A    2016  100   90  130
     2017  120  120  160
     2018  160  130  190
B    2016  200  290  230
     2017  220  220  260
     2018  260  230  290
C    2016  300  390  330
     2017  320  320  360
     2018  360  330  390
```

Comment: I want  one top row only  City, Year, X, Y, Z

Comment: There is one top row. `Sales` is the name of column axis. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars = ["City", "Sales"], 
            value_vars=["2016","2017","2018"], 
            var_name="Year")
      .pivot(index=["City","Year"], columns="Sales", values="value")

Sales        X    Y    Z
City Year               
A    2016  100   90  130
     2017  120  120  160
     2018  160  130  190
B    2016  200  290  230
     2017  220  220  260
     2018  260  230  290
C    2016  300  390  330
     2017  320  320  360
     2018  360  330  390
```

Comment: I want  one top row only  City, Year, X, Y, Z

Comment: You can add a `.reset_index()` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

#### `Pivot` and `stack`

```
df.pivot('City', 'Sales').stack(0).rename_axis(['City', 'Year'])
```

---

```
Sales        X    Y    Z
City Year               
A    2016  100   90  130
     2017  120  120  160
     2018  160  130  190
B    2016  200  290  230
     2017  220  220  260
     2018  260  230  290
C    2016  300  390  330
     2017  320  320  360
     2018  360  330  390
```

Comment: I want one top header row only City, Year, X, Y, Z

Comment: @SSS You can reset the index, Check `df.pivot('City', 'Sales').stack(0).rename_axis(['City', 'Year']).reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks it works, Is there any other way that if I get those values according to the original Table sorting order, Now in this case it has sorted ascending alphabetically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What do you mean by `according to the original Table sorting order,`?

Comment: The data I'm getting from the API, I need to have it in exact same order but after using this is showing in alphabetical order

Comment: I'm assuming you want to preserve the order in the City column? and AFAIK there is no simple way to do. Preserving order will require some more pandas operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for! However, it worked for some files, but not for others with same structure. Not sure why, probably too many to repeat and pivot. I found that if I sort the data frame by the key fields before pivot, it works for any file. So, in the example above, you would need to sort on at least the key 'City'; in my own work, I sort both fields like 'City' and 'Year' just in case. I thought of this because it's required for SAS proc transpose.

Comment: Welcome to SO! .. could you add a code example to your Answer so it's easier to follow? as-is, it seems a better fit as a comment (though I recognize you need more reputation to create them)